# Cron Expression confusion in the Spring Framework

Tags: cron

My scheduler's application context defines this trgger:

```
<bean id="myTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
   <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob"/>
   <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 ∗ ∗ ∗ ?"/>
</bean>
```

Does it fire every day at 00:00? Or every hour?
I'd say the latter, but the documentation of this project says otherwise...
Can you help me out?
Are there different kind of expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is using quartz for scheduling jobs so it is definitely **every hour**.
Please check:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06